# javascript/jquery loaded in div can't use functions in initial page load

Tags: jquery, scope, typeerror

My code is built as follows:
Initial page load. 
jquery library and Noty plugin gets loaded with script tag.
I can successfully create a Noty notification(in a script tag). In the same page.

I include a js file later and when I use the same code from a function in that js file to use a Noty notification there I get an error:
TypeError: noty is not a function

What am I doing wrong?
Is this some kind of scope issue?

Includes in the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/transferlist.js"></script>
```

Works.
Now a div gets created and content for this diff is loaded through jquery.
Therein a function is called from within transferlist.js (showstatusmessage).

That's when I get the error:
TypeError: noty is not a function

```
function showstatusmessage(message) {
        var noty = noty({
          text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!',
          type: 'alert',
          timeout: 5000
        });
}
```

Any help with understanding/resolving this issue is very appreciated!

EDIT:
I changed the calls to 
    var noti = noty(...
Now I'm getting:
TypeError: jQuery.noty is undefined @ jquery.noty.js:455
jQuery is loaded in the main page so I would expect I don't have to load it again here... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first assignment:

```
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

overwrote the function you were calling, so the next time you try it with

```
var noty = noty({
      text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!',
      type: 'alert',
      timeout: 5000
    });
```

all you find is the previous, globally defined, `var noty` and not the function you were looking for. Try using a different variable name for those assignments.

Comment: I believe I understand the issue. Javascript doesn't make a difference between a function and a variable and by doing the assignment above I overwrite the function with the return value of noty. Is my understanding correct? Note that this is code that came from there own website (which to me is a bit silly). I changed it to var noti = noty... I'm now getting another error now: [10:38:50.167] TypeError: jQuery.noty is undefined @ .../noty/jquery.noty.js:455

Comment: I seem to have to include the js files each in each new dynamic content that is loaded. Is this normal? Or is there a more proper way to handle this?